# Understanding what is happening to a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am relatively new to code and specially vectors. I was looking at some code online and couldnt quite understand what was happening.

I understand most syntax involving vectors just not this...

Code Section:

```
vector< vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
//find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
//use moments method to find our filtered object
double refArea = 0;
bool objectFound = false;
if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
    int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
    //if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS we have a noisy filter
    if(numObjects<MAX_NUM_OBJECTS){
        for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {
```

Part i do not understand:

```
for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {
```

What are the two square brackets referring to ? I understand that a vector can be accessed like a array but what is the second pair of square brackets doing?

Please help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: The `Vec4i` class apparently also supports `operator []`.

Comment: Looks like the second set of square brackets is to access the 0th member of the `Vec4i` that gets returned by the first set of square brackets accessing the vector.

Comment: OpenCV appears to be popular lately. Why don't you read its documentation?

Comment: @Guvante well look at that. apparently. Phat Phingers =P No wonder it looked so hideous. Thanks.